# Javascript select the child by the parents id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

sorry if this question has already been asked but how can i select a child(li) by the parents(ul) id?
code:

```
    <ul onmouseover="openNav()" onmouseout="closeNav()" id="nav">
        <li><a href="link1.html">Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
    </ul>

function openNav(){
   //document.getElementById('nav').style.height = '65px'; <-- this is working
   document.getElementById('nav').childNodes.style.opacity = '1';
}
```

I've already tried this:

```
document.getElementById('nav').getElementsByTagName('li').style.opacity = '1';
```

and this:

```
document.getElementById('nav').childNodes.style.opacity = '1';
```

and a few other but none is working pls help me!!
Thanks for all answers :)

Comment: have to loop over `childNodes`

Answer (score 2):

`.childNodes` will return an array if there are multiple child nodes selected. To change all of them:

```
var childNodesArray = document.getElementById('nav').childNodes;
for(var i = 0; i < childNodesArray.length; i++){
  childNodesArray[i].style.opacity = '1';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you want to select all childrens, but Try :

```js
$('#nav').children('li').each(function(){
     console.log($(this).html());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul onmouseover="openNav()" onmouseout="closeNav()" id="nav">
  <li><a href="link1.html">Link 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you chose to use jQuery please take advantage of it and avoid inline JavaScript. The `this` keyword in each callback refers to the `li` element where as `$(this).parent()` refers to the `ul` element:

```
$(function() {
    $('#nav > li').on('mouseenter', function() {
        //your code goes here
    })
    .on('mouseleave', function() {
        //your code goes here
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just do...

```
$("#nav").find("li").css({"opacity" : "1"});
```

If you're styling every li that is a child of that #nav ul then you don't need an iterator or a loop or anything, that'll apply it to all of them.

Answer (score 0):

```
var lis = document.getElementById('nav').children; //childNodes will give you text nodes as well. You don't want that. That is why children
```

Then iterate over the `lis` collection and apply style.

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(lis, function(li){
    li.style.opacity = '1';
});
```